# Android Sqlite database column defined in Create table script but not creating on table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a the below table script:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_XXX + "("
                    + XXX_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + XXX_ITEM_NO + "TEXT,"
                    + XXX_DETAILS +"TEXT,"
                    + XXX_EXP_DATE + "TEXT,"
                    + XXX_IS_OK +"INTEGER, "
                    + XXX_CODE + "TEXT"
                    + ")";
```

But when I'm going to insert data getting the error , **TABLE_XXX has no column named XXX_IS_OK**.

how to overcome it.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you incremented your database version number / cleaned up old database files so that `onUpgrade()` or `onCreate()` are called?

Comment: there should be space between variable and column constraints like  `XXX_ITEM_NO + " TEXT,"`. If no space, then string will be merged, Table will not get created throwing an exception..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need give some spaces on the code. Before the quotation marks.

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_XXX + "("   
+ XXX_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "   
+ XXX_ITEM_NO + " TEXT, "     
+ XXX_DETAILS +" TEXT, "   
+ XXX_EXP_DATE + " TEXT, "   
+ XXX_IS_OK + " INTEGER, "
+ XXX_CODE + " TEXT "   
+ ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are missing whitespaces in your statement.

```
+ XXX_IS_OK +"INTEGER, "
```

should be:

```
+ XXX_IS_OK +" INTEGER, "
```