# .SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, database, sqlite, syntax-error

What am I missing? Something with a "," but I seem to be looking in the wrong place. This is my code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                KEY_CURSUS + "," +
                KEY_ONDERDEEL + "," +
                KEY_GAME + "," +
                KEY_TIJD + "," +
                KEY_WEB + "," +
                KEY_CHECK + "," +
                " UNIQUE (" + KEY_ROWID +"));";
```

And this is the error I get:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE if not exists Games_getset (_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,cursus,onderdeel,game,tijd,web,check, UNIQUE (_id));
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718178/android-sqlite-database-column-defined-in-create-table-script-but-not-creating-o/18718292#18718292

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename or quote the `check` column since [`check` is a keyword in SQL](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

For example:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
            KEY_CURSUS + "," +
            KEY_ONDERDEEL + "," +
            KEY_GAME + "," +
            KEY_TIJD + "," +
            KEY_WEB + "," +
            + "`" + KEY_CHECK + "`," +
            " UNIQUE (" + KEY_ROWID +"));";
```

Comment: Thanks laalto (and CRUSADER)!

Comment: I made the same mistake by naming a column as 'cast'. I realized the mistake after reading your answer. Thanks

Comment: Same problem for me except my column name was 'group'

Answer (score -1):

You need to add data type for the columns you are defining for your table. You have added integer dataType for `KEY_ROWID` but forgot to add dataTypes for the rest..

```
.........KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                KEY_CURSUS + " text," +
                KEY_ONDERDEEL + " text," + ........
and so on...
```

Comment: This isn't the issue - it's all right to have columns with just the name specified. The problem is using a reserved word `check` as a column name which confuses the SQL parser.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting "IF NOT EXIST" in the create table command, SQLite in android version 4.0.4 give me this error, and not in 4.4.2

Luck.